# I'm doing performance testing using Artillery, But getting 400 status code

Tags: artillery

```
config:
  environments:
    dev:
      target: "https://dev.api.serverless-accelerator.myApp.io/serverless-accelerator"
    local:
      target: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/serverless-accelerator"
  defaults:
    headers: {
        Correlation-Object: '{"correlationId":"any value is ok"}',
        Connection: "keep-alive",
      }
  phases:
    - duration: 10
      arrivalRate: 5
      name: Warm up

scenarios:
  - name: "test"
    flow:
      - post:
          url: "/example-data"
          json:
            name: "{{New API Test33}}"
            email: "{{abcd@xyz.test}}"
            exampleNumber: 5
            address:
              '{
                address1: "{{123 state}}"
                city: "{{New York}}"
                zipOrPostalCode: "{{12345}}"
                country: "{{US}}"
              }'
```